# ioHook on electron consumes too much CPU. Is there anyway around? Or alternative to ioHook

Tags: node.js, reactjs, io, electron, cpu

I am tracking users' mouse movement and upon receiving mouse movement emitter, I dispatch an event that does it work.

```
ioHook.on('mousemove', event => {
    dispatch(storeLatestWorkTimeStamp())
});
```

Sometimes the electron app consumes too much CPU more than **skype** and **slack**.

I tried setting the max listeners though

```
ioHook.setMaxListeners(10);
```

But it's not helping in the consumption of the CPU.

Below is the screenshot of the output of the ***htop*** [image: htop output]

The usage varies from 60 to 90. Is there any way to control the CPU usage of ioHook.

Is there any other npm packages that serve the purpose as [ioHook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iohook).

Answer (score -2):

Sorry that I am posting an answer to my own question. After R & D'ing with my colleague, I found out that this can be handled using a functionality called `Power Monitor` provided by the Electron.

Especially [`powerMonitor.getSystemIdleTime()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/power-monitor#powermonitorgetsystemidletime) comes in handy and it consumes way less RAM compared to ioHook.

For more information, you can refer to https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/power-monitor. Hope this was helpful.

Comment: this doesn't make any sense

Comment: You were looking for an alternative to iohook and provided a mouseMove example, but the powerMonitor function you posted doesn't do anything related.